# what is the difference between using roscreate-pkg and creating a package by hand?

Tags: ros, roscreate-pkg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

tutorials teaches me two way creating ROS package
1.roscreate-pkg
2. creating a package by hand
what is the difference between using roscreate-pkg and creating a package by hand?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35386/what-is-the-difference-between-using-roscreate-pkg-and-creating-a-package-by-hand?/) by [rosmaker](https://answers.ros.org/users/2491/rosmaker/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2012-05-31

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you do it correctly, nothing. However, using roscreate-pkg is easier, and you'll be a lot less likely to make a mistake.

What you want to be really careful of is creating a package by copying files from an existing one ... its tempting, but tends to cause obnoxious problems.

For more details, see the [roscreate](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscreate) wiki page

---

Originally posted by [lindzey](https://answers.ros.org/users/2444/lindzey/) with karma: 1780 on 2012-05-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3